# bitcoinj testnet transaction decode problem

Tags: java, bitcoinj, bitcoin-testnet

I'm trying to decode testnet transaction using bitcoinj 0.14.7.
This is HEX of the transaction I'm trying to decode:

```
02000000000101ef4c1c3c60028b050a5798265c0b37719418dd71b0621e76a68a47d5d9eef55f000000001716001467d7c32c0dad98bf8dd3dea81cbb1dbd4ea4afb5feffffff02b7df02000000000017a914ebb55a85454dc15589b8a87bab4b438892b54c0c87b0ad0100000000001976a914140b85a1c430c8f4fd1f91ae1c7451902b8ce76c88ac024730440220359623836f97e9e4c04917455ed2f9fb2343b0bf96853d47313b0c96d828c889022046da37bfda03cf3481e3ef5c5b5e655d6fd280c2aec2831b6494a8207b76655b01210224c44e1af98b5c28ebf822b65e4a2872d0780b4b6935b3100f60d3ac3b78cb00b2f81500
```

When I go to the blockcipher https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/decodetx/ and decode the transaction there - it's decoded no problem. But when I'm trying to do this:

```
Transaction tx = new Transaction(params, HexUtils.hexToBytes(txHex));
LOGGER.info(tx.toString());
```

it prints

```
4c67f1e1b10b063210e59400466383fb18634c05430d4f53795a16216dd34ffd 
version 2 
INCOMPLETE: No inputs! 
out [exception: Push of data element that is larger than remaining data] 
prps UNKNOWN
```

Also, I checked my code against master and it worded like a charm! Here is the output:

```
65b47da760fb781a80e8607e19c82454f12c4ee8dd699045d4e96c869e07bf25
version 2
time locked until block 1439922
in PUSHDATA(22)[001467d7c32c0dad98bf8dd3dea81cbb1dbd4ea4afb5]
witness:30440220359623836f97e9e4c04917455ed2f9fb2343b0bf96853d47313b0c96d828c889022046da37bfda03cf3481e3ef5c5b5e655d6fd280c2aec2831b6494a8207b76655b01 0224c44e1af98b5c28ebf822b65e4a2872d0780b4b6935b3100f60d3ac3b78cb00
outpoint:5ff5eed9d5478aa6761e62b071dd189471370b5c2698570a058b02603c1c4cef:0
sequence:fffffffe
out HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[ebb55a85454dc15589b8a87bab4b438892b54c0c] EQUAL 0.00188343 BTC
P2SH addr:2NEjY32rnrCdi8Cve6yJ4RaPanugBnJ8fme
out DUP HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[140b85a1c430c8f4fd1f91ae1c7451902b8ce76c] EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG 0.0011 BTC
P2PKH addr:mhLwcTEoquZcAjT34fD4uPySUAdK77uqvL
prps UNKNOWN
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code just creating a transaction object so that's not enough.

Your requirement is fetching a transaction from block. So You need to connect a testnet node. Just create a PeerGroup connect local or remote bitcoin testnet node.

Check that example below.

```
    final NetworkParameters params = TestNet3Params.get();

    BlockStore blockStore = new MemoryBlockStore(params);
    BlockChain chain = new BlockChain(params, blockStore);
    PeerGroup peerGroup = new PeerGroup(params, chain);
    peerGroup.start();
    // Alternatively you can connect your localhost or another working testnet node
    peerGroup.addAddress(new PeerAddress(params, "testnet-seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch", 18333));
    peerGroup.waitForPeers(1).get();
    Peer peer = peerGroup.getConnectedPeers().get(0);

    Sha256Hash txHash = Sha256Hash.wrap(hexString);
    ListenableFuture<Transaction> future = peer.getPeerMempoolTransaction(txHash);
    System.out.println("Waiting for node to send us the requested transaction: " + txHash);
    Transaction tx = future.get();
    System.out.println(tx);
```

Comment: I'm trying to decode the transaction. Fetching transaction from block will return me same transaction payload HEX that I'm trying to decode. I'm trying to decode full transaction HEX, not the transaction hash.

Comment: May you share what do you try exactly in your code?

Comment: I'm just trying to decode the transaction, e.g. get the inputs, outputs, scripts, witnesses etc.